# When defining an internal variable with _ like self._split_dict, why it directly generates both self._split_dict and self.split_dict?

Tags: python

I was looking at a repo on GitHub and found the following question:
The author defines a variable

```
self._split_dict = {
            'train': 0,
            'id_val': 1,
            'test': 2,
            'val': 3
        }
```

And later he directly calls the `self.split_dict` like

```
self._metadata_df.loc[val_center_mask, 'split'] = self.split_dict['val']
```

I also found the command line of defining `self._split_dict` generates both `self._split_dict` and `self.split_dict` by debugging.
So what actually happens here and why do sometimes people use `self._split_dict` and at other times use `self.split_dict`?

The question has been solved. There is another method called `split_dict` coming into the class.

Comment: Can you share the repo for more context?

Comment: Could you link the repo? I don't think that Python does this without additional "magic". And welcome to StackOverflow, by the way! 

Comment: Welcome to SO! Both names are not 'generated'. Perhaps the other method/attribute is coming into the class by inheritance? Anyway, you need to share some code where it looks as if it does

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get it. There is another defined method coming into the class by inheritance.